# mongodb indexable $and query possible?

Tags: mongodb

I'm developing an app using a MongoDB database that needs to check for items enabled for today's particular weekday.
Items can be enabled for any individual days of the week. (eg: Monday and Wednesday, or Tuesday and Thursday and Saturday, every day, whatever)

I was going to do this:
`var currentWeekDay = Math.pow(2,new Date().getDay());`

Therefore

```
Sunday === 1
Monday === 2
Tuesday === 4
Wednesday === 8
...
Saturday === 64
```

An example item might be like this
`{_id:'blah', weekDays:127}`

Now I want to query all items that are enabled for today...

MongoDB has an operator $and, but that's only for logical operations.
It has $bitsAnySet, but it looks like it's only implemented in 3.16.
https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-3518
I'm running MongoDB v2.6.10.

So I'm wondering how to come up with a sensible indexable query.

Maybe

```
{_id:'blah', w0:1, w1:1, w2:1, w3:1, w4:1, w5:1, w6:1} //every day
{_id:'blah', w0:1, w1:0, w2:0, w3:0, w4:0, w5:0, w6:1} //Sat and Sun
```

That would be easily indexable. Can anyone think of a more terse way of doing it?

Comment: Yes it is possible. Is it wise? No. See the answer from @sheliak

Answer (score 2):

One option would be storing days as an array of integers:

```
{ '_id' : '1' , 'weekDays' : [0,1,2,3,4] } // mon-fri
{ '_id' : '2' , 'weekDays' : [5,6] } // sat-sun
```

Then you could create a simple index on weekDays field:

```
db.collection.createIndex({ weekDays : 1 })
```

And querying would also be pretty simple:

```
db.collection.find({weekDays : 2}) // wed
```